# ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule) - Using DI for angular content translation

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, internationalization

I have an angular project which has the following architecture (i removed hml & css) :

```
|_ app.component.ts
|_ app.module.ts
|_ app-routing-module.ts
|_ components
   |_ site
        |_ site.component.ts
        |_ site.module.ts
        |_ site.en.module.ts
        |_ site.fr.module.ts
        |_ site-routing-module.ts
           |_ home
               |_ home.component.ts
               |_ home.module.ts
               |_ home.en.module.ts
               |_ home.fr.module.ts
               |_ home-routing-module.ts
                   |_ pdf-viewer-form
                       |_ pdf-viewer-form.component.ts
                   |_ pdf-viewer-from-server
                       |_ pdf-viewer-from-server.component.ts
           |_ info
               |_ info.component.ts
               |_ info.module.ts
               |_ info.en.module.ts
               |_ info.fr.module.ts
               |_ info-routing-module.ts
   |_ theme
           |_ header
               |_ header.component.ts
               |_ header.module.ts
               |_ header.en.module.ts
               |_ header.fr.module.ts
               |_ header-routing-module.ts
```

For this project I tried to implement i18n using dependency injection and lazy-loading.
For this I implemented a typescript file with this content :

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { en } from './en.translation';

export enum WebsiteLanguage {
  English = 'en',
  French = 'fr',
}
export type Translation = typeof en;
export const TRANSLATION = new InjectionToken<Translation>('TRANSLATION');
```

And a translation file :

```
export const fr = {
  language: 'Français',
  home: {
    title: 'La page d\'accueil marche',
  },
  upload: {
    title: 'La page Upload marche!',
  },

  langsSupported: (n: number) => `Cette démon inclut ${n} langues ${n === 1 ? '' : 's'}.`,
};
```

My app.component.html is:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Concerning the app-routing.module.ts contains the routes which allow lazy loading:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: WebsiteLanguage.English,
    loadChildren: () => import ("./components/site/site.en.module").then(m => m.SiteEnModule)
  }, // lazy loading the English site module
  {
    path: WebsiteLanguage.French,
    loadChildren: () => import ("./components/site/site.fr.module").then(m => m.SiteFrModule)
  },   // lazy loading the Czech site module

  {path: '**', redirectTo: WebsiteLanguage.English},  // redirecting to default route in case of any other prefix
];
```

If we have a look at the site.fr.module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    // CommonModule,
    SiteModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // providing the value of english translation data
    {provide: TRANSLATION, useValue: fr},
  ],
})
export class SiteFrModule { }
```

Finally my SiteModule is simple:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SiteRoutingModule,
    // RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class SiteModule { }
```

In my site.component html :

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let translation of translations">
    <a [routerLink]="['/', translation[1]]">{{translation[0]}} ({{translation[1]}})</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<!-- simple navigation links to switch between two "translated" views -->
<a routerLink="home">home</a>
<a routerLink="info">info</a>
```

And my SiteComponent is injecting the translation:

```
export class SiteComponent implements OnInit {

  // this will extract tuple of translation key and name from enum
  translations = Object.entries(WebsiteLanguage);

  constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATION) public readonly lang: Translation) {
    // just a simple log to demonstrate usage in component class
    console.log('current language is', lang.language);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

I can navigate easily and change the language in the url and i have the correct translations.
Now, my issue is that I have a menu which is in app.component.html.
I could have used built in i18n tools in angular but i wanted to use json object to set the different translated statics contents.

I tried to create a header modules and the header routing.
I replicate the code used for SiteComponent.

For example my route have this definition:

```
const headerRoutes: Routes = [
  // loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  // loadChildren: './info/info.module#InfoModule'
  {
    path: '',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import ("../../site/home/home.module").then(m => m.HomeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'info',
        loadChildren: () => import ("../../site/info/info.module").then(m => m.InfoModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(headerRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HeaderRoutingModule {}
```

My HTML :

```
<a routerLink="home">From file</a> |
<a routerLink="info">From server</a>
```

I unfortunatelly obtain this error message:

```
core.js:6479 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken TRANSLATION -> InjectionToken TRANSLATION -> InjectionToken TRANSLATION]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TRANSLATION!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:11101)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11268)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25332)
    at Object.get (core.js:25046)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14737)
```

By commenting the following lines in my header.component.ts file:

```
// constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATION) public readonly lang: Translation) {
//   // just a simple log to demonstrate usage in component class
//   console.log('current language is', lang.language);
// }
```

the page is displayed, the site component is translating the content based on the translation file.

I have 2 issues:

- how can i inject the TRANSLATION without breaking all the application ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue just after posting the question.
My app.component.html is modified :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I added the header in the site component:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let translation of translations">
    <a [routerLink]="['/', translation[1]]">{{translation[0]}} ({{translation[1]}})</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<!-- simple navigation links to switch between two "translated" views -->
<a routerLink="home">home</a>
<a routerLink="info">info</a>
```

Finally I uncomment the constructor from header component:

```
constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATION) public readonly lang: Translation) {
    // just a simple log to demonstrate usage in component class
    console.log('current language is', lang.language);
}
```

I also remove the following scripts:

1. header.module.ts
2. header.en.module.ts
3. header.fr.module.ts
4. header-routing-module.ts

Happy end...